# Add apostrophe and other characters to attribute of Hyperlink Object in ASP.NET VB

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
Dim hyp = New HyperLink()
hyp.ID = a_taglist(itags)
hyp.Attributes.Add("onmousedown", "return clk('" & a_taglist(itags) & "')")
panel1.Controls.Add(hyp)
```

I want the row:

```
hyp.Attributes.Add("onmousedown", "return clk('" & a_taglist(itags) & "')")
```

To add a onmousedown attribute to the hyperlink.

It kind of works but it gets replaced with `& # 39`;

```
 onmousedown="return clk(& #39;bavaria& #39;)"
```

How can I avoid this.  I've tried to `"\"` escape it out and sending it `char(&#39)` already.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are these #39; breaking your client side script?

Comment: have you tried `"javascript:return clk('" & a_taglist(itags) & "')"`?

Comment: @Netricity your right, it was fine, just hard to read now :(   the problem was the onmousedown event won't fire more than once.

Comment: @valverij   no you don't need "javascript:",  i remember that from somewhere before, if its in onmouse= etc.  its needed for the href= tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a security feature [introduced (apparently) in .NET 4.0](http://forums.asp.net/t/1554455.aspx/). The point is to prevent XSS attacks but in practice, it shouldn't be a problem for you.

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c7TcG/), for example.

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="alert(&#39;Hello&#39;);" />
```

Comment: http://compgroups.net/comp.lang.javascript/onmousedown-is-not-what-i-expect-in-java/349643

Comment: yeah it was fine.   the problem was the onmousedown event only fires once.  my js was toggling an effect and i though it was broken js.